# After request permission in react-native application got java error and application closing

Tags: android, react-native

Can anybody help with this: 
After making request for permission (CAMERA, one of location or another), got error:

```js
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
      {
        title: "Cool Photo App Camera Permission",
        message:
          "Cool Photo App needs access to your camera " +
          "so you can take awesome pictures.",
        buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
        buttonNegative: "Cancel",
        buttonPositive: "OK"
      }
```

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.av_ua/com.av_ua.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback.invoke(java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3516)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3556)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback.invoke(java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference
 at com.facebook.react.modules.permissions.PermissionsModule.onRequestPermissionsResult(PermissionsModule.java:207)
 at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate$2.invoke(ReactActivityDelegate.java:169)
 at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.onResume(ReactActivityDelegate.java:100)
 at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onResume(ReactActivity.java:56)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1270)
 at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6958)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3493)
 ... 8 more
```

What can I try to resolve this issue?